# Virtualhost Apache and Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl, virtualhost

I have Tomcat and Apache web server. by MOD_JK I configure Apache to send request for `http://127.0.0.1/cas` to Tomcat.
`http://127.0.0.1/cas` works correctly and Tomcat response to it.
now I want this `https://127.0.0.1/cas` to work, (SSL).

I search it and found that I need Virtualhost on Apache that send requests to Tomcat, my question is how can I create a SSL Virtualhost?
and should I remove all configuration that I create before this for `http://127.0.0.1/cas`?

Comment: Is it Jasig CAS? Which versions of httpd and tomcat are you targeting?

Comment: Configuring Virtual hosts in Apache is probably more appropriate in ServerFault or WebMasters.

Comment: it's Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)  and tomcat 7.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of online examples for httpd SSL virtual host configuration.  Just specify something similar to the following, and put your mod_jk JKMount references inside of it.

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.100.10:443

<VirtualHost 192.168.100.100:443>
  ServerName  domain.com:443
  UseCanonicalName Off

  CustomLog    /var/log/httpd/domain.log combined
  ErrorLog     /var/log/httpd/domain-error.log

  SSLEngine on
  SSLVerifyClient none
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/domain.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/domain.com.key

  SSLProxyEngine on

  SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
   nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
   downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: whats the meaning of "SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
   nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
   downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0"

Comment: Some versions of IE have problems with keepalive and SSL.  There's various descriptions of this on the web, see for example: http://www.modssl.org/docs/2.8/ssl_faq.html#ToC49

Comment: Actually, digging into this, I note that this may be outmoded.  See http://newestindustry.org/2007/06/06/dear-apache-software-foundation-fix-the-msie-ssl-keepalive-settings/  and https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49484